# is Java weak typed as this example demonstrates when compared with python?

Tags: java, python, string, string-concatenation, strong-typing

I familiar with what strong and weak types are. I also know that Java is strongly typed.
now I learn python and it is a strong typed language. But now I see python is "more" strongly typed than Java. example to illustrate

```
public class StringConcat {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      String s="hello ";
      s+=4;
    System.out.println(s);
}
}
```

No error and prints hello 4

in python

```
>>> x="hello"
>>> x+=4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

so this example demonstrates that python is strongly typed. unless Java under the hood, does some manipulation to convert int to String and do String concat.

Comment: _unless Java under the hood, does some manipulation to convert int to String and do String concat._ Yes it does that.

Comment: String concatenation is a very special case in Java.  There's language in the JLS that says an automatic conversion (using `toString`) takes place for the "+" operator (and this applies to `+=` as Prashant pointed out), but there is no other similar case where this sort of conversion between "unrelated" types takes place.  I wouldn't call Java "weakly typed" because of this one exception to the rules.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java is still strongly typed, despite your example. The code is equivalent to

```
String s = "hello ";
s = s + 4;
```

and Java will convert the `4` into a string, then perform the string concatenation. This is a language feature.

In Python, however, you cannot use `+` to concatenate `4` to your string, because the language will not take the liberty of converting it to a `str`. As you point out, Java does this for you under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

This example doesn't prove Java isn't strongly typed.  There's just an implicit [*string conversion* (JLS, Section 5.1.11)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11) going on behind the scenes.

First, conversion to a reference type occurs to create an `Integer` from the `int` literal (`new Integer(4)`), then `toString()` is called to convert it to a `String` for concatenation.

Comment: I don't think that requires boxing. I wasn't around before autoboxing, but I think the code still worked back then. Also, `StringBuilder` has [`append` overloads for primitives](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append(int)).

Comment: @user2357112 The JLS link I provided doesn't make any mention of boxing, it's just "converted to a reference value".  I've changed that part of my answer.

Comment: @user2357112: The JLS definition is that when + is used on a String and something else, the toString() method is called on the other operand--and primitives like `int` don't have toString() or any other methods.  So it has to be "boxed" (or whatever you want to call it) to an Object.  Could be that the JLS had some special language to handle this case before autoboxing--I wouldn't know.

Comment: Looks like the JLS [mentions that implementations are free to optimize away unnecessary conversions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1), but it defines the results in terms of an equivalent, less efficient implementation. Actual JVMs won't create the intermediate `Integer` or `String` objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want another funny example, you can find in many places the ugly

intNumber+""

to convert a number to string. Programmers are lazy and don't want to write

Integer.toString(intNumber)

And this causes a string conversion AND a useless string concatenation at runtime.

This does not mean Java is not strong typed, simply all Objects need to have a toString() method, and all primitives can be automatically boxed and unboxed to their non-primitive counterparts (int -> Integer, long -> Long etc..) which implement toString(), and "+" in java acts as string concatenation.